# C : program to calculate GPA for students

Tags: c, function, struct

Whenever I insert 2 or more students, the program gives the same gpa from the first student. I insert  for both every time, and how can I display the max gpa and who got it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *f;

struct student 
{
    char name[20];
    int id;
    int n;
    float sum;
    float gpa;
} s[100];

float FUN_GPA(int n);

int main ()
{
    int m,i,x,b;
    float max=0;


    s[i].sum=0;

    printf("Please Enter Number Of Students : ");
    scanf("%d",&m);

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        printf("\nStudent %d : \n",i+1);

        printf("Name : ");
        scanf("%s",&s[i].name);

        printf("ID : ");
        scanf("%d",&s[i].id);

        printf("Number Of Courses : ");
        scanf("%d",&s[i].n);

    }
    printf("\nEnter Student Marks");
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t......[ Student %d ]......\n",i+1);

        for(x=0;x<s[i].n;x++)
        {
            printf("Course %d Mark : ",x+1);
            scanf("%d",&b);

            s[i].sum+=b;
        }
        printf("\nSum Of The Courses Marks = %3.f",s[i].sum);
        printf("\nGPA For Student %d = %f",i+1,FUN_GPA(s[i].gpa)); 


    }   
    if (s[i].gpa>max)
        max=s[i].gpa;
    printf("\n\nHighest GPA is done by Student %d with GPA = %f",i,max);

    {

        if((f=fopen("d:\\STUDENTS.txt","w"))==NULL)
            printf("\ncant open file ");
//      if((f=fopen("d:\\STUDENTS.txt","r"))==NULL)
//      printf("\ncant open file ");

        fprintf(f,"Name : %s\t ID : %d\t GPA = %f \n",s[i].name,s[i].id,s[i].gpa);

        fclose(f);
    }
}

float FUN_GPA(int i)
{
    s[i].gpa=0;
    s[i].gpa=s[i].sum/s[i].n;

    return s[i].gpa;
}
```

Comment: What is GPA? Please elaborate

Comment: gpa is the grade or in other word gpa=sum of grades/number of courses

Comment: GPA is weighted based on credits though, so you're missing a grade*credits + grade*credits .... / sum of credits

Comment: the teacher dont want to add credits , in the question he asked calculate gpa and between brackets he wrote ( gpa = sum/number of courses )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `FUN_GPA(s[i].gpa)` by `FUN_GPA(i)`.

Put this *inside* the loop; not much use having it *outside*:

```
if (s[i].gpa>max)
    max=s[i].gpa;
```

The same applies to this initializer, by the way:

```
s[i].sum=0;
```

In general, **do not use** variable `i` outside the loop; this is bad practice and in your particular case, totally wrong!
`i` is not the index of the best performing student; it is not even a correct index once the loop ends, since it refers to the array element immediately following the last registered student. Please introduce a new variable to keep track of the index of the best performer so far. Instead of `i`, use this new variable in the lines to follow:

```
fprintf(f,"Name : %s\t ID : %d\t GPA = %f \n",s[i].name,s[i].id,s[i].gpa);
```

Same here; do not forget to add 1 like you did everywhere else already!

```
printf("\n\nHighest GPA is done by Student %d with GPA = %f",i,max);
```

General advice: use descriptive names. `i` is OK afaic; `s` and `n` are not so great, `m`, `x` and `b` would have been good for 50 lashes from *my* old teachers for sure!

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be in a for loop (you're only checking one as it is currently written):

```
if (s[i].gpa>max)
    max=s[i].gpa;
```

You'll probably also want to keep track of which `i` had the `max`.

So something like:

```
int iwithmax;

for ( i = 0 ; i < m ; i++) {
    if (s[i].gpa > max) {
        max = s[i].gpa;
        iwithmax = i;
    }
}
```

and change print statement accordingly:

```
printf("\n\nHighest GPA is done by Student %d with GPA = %f",iwithmax,max);
```